ApiPlatform returns empty array in stead of empty object for empty ManyToOne relation
In a Symfony v7 with ApiPlatform v3 project I have an entity product that refer to a single entity image using a ManyToOne relationship. Using the application/vnd.api+json (jsonapi) format, the hash contains a reference to the MediaObject. When there is a relation, it shows an object like it should with a ManyToOne relationship. When it does not have a relation, the data is set to an empty array.
With relation
...
"image": {
  "data": {
    "type": "MediaObject",
    "id": "/api/media-objects/67"
  }
},
...

Without relation
...
"image": {
  "data": []
},
...

This is not only for this specific entity relation, but for all ManyToOne relationships in my project. Is this a bug or is this configurable?
In ApiPlatform v2 it did not include the property at all when it was empty.

Are you sure your serialization groups allow to get the data from the parent to the children ? If the array is empty, it means it found data, but cannot display the content since the serialization context doesn't allow.

Yes I'm using serialization groups and they are properly configured. If serialization groups where the issue, then it should still not be an array in stead of an object when it is not a many-to-many relation (in my option).
